# KTor server - 400 error with azure app service

Tags: azure, kotlin, azure-web-app-service, ktor, ktor-client

I am running ktor server with netty. We had EmbeddedServer() earlier and we moved to EngineMain() to accommodate yaml(conf) config file. It looks like we are getting 400 Bad Request after the changes. Does KTor server validates the headers by default to send 400?

ktorVersion=2.3.0

The application does not have RequestValidation{} nor StatusPages modules, not sure if adding them will help?

OK, added the statuspage, but hitting it for any error. Strangly this happens with Azure App Service, but when run locally the Ktor service responds and works as expected.

Request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Host: xxx-yyyyyy-zzzzzzzzzz-aaaaa.azurewebsites.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US
Max-Forwards: 10
DNT: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
X-ARR-LOG-ID: c0e417c3-aaaa-bbbb-cccc-ddddcd626ef9
CLIENT-IP: x.x.x.x:45628
X-Client-IP: x.x.x.x
DISGUISED-HOST: xxx-yyyyyy-zzzzzzzzzz-aaaaa.azurewebsites.net
X-SITE-DEPLOYMENT-ID: xxx-yyyyyy-zzzzzzzzzz-aaaaa-aaa__f6ad
WAS-DEFAULT-HOSTNAME: xxx-yyyyyy-zzzzzzzzzz-aaaaa.azurewebsites.net
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-AppService-Proto: https
X-ARR-SSL: 2048|256|CN=Microsoft Azure TLS Issuing CA 02, O=Microsoft Corporation, C=US|CN=*.azurewebsites.net, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=WA, C=US
X-Forwarded-TlsVersion: 1.2
X-Forwarded-For: x.x.x.x:45628
X-Original-URL: /
X-WAWS-Unencoded-URL: /
X-Client-Port: 45628
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
```

Comment: Ktor doesn't validate request headers, but the underlying engine may validate them. Can you please share a dump of the request which causes the server to respond with 400?

Comment: Note that the https part is handled by the App service and the application(Ktor EngineMain) gets a http requests. While local, we use http requests directly.

Comment: Also, note that the total size of the packet is about 1556 bytes and TCP payload is 1460 bytes.

Comment: Since you cannot reproduce the problem locally, may the Azure App Service itself reject the request?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman, I checked that and found that the 400 response comes from the Ktor application's port. So it is sure that the response is coming from Ktor application. Also, with the same setup with application running on EmbeddedServer() the requests are successful. This issue is only with EngineMain().

Comment: Then, can you share your `application.conf` file?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman, below is the config application.conf file:


ktor {
    deployment {
        host = "0.0.0.0"
        port = 8098
        port = ${?WEBSITES_PORT}
        maxInitialLineLength = 2048
        maxHeaderSize = 1024
        maxChunkSize = 42
    }
    application {
        modules = [ xxxx.yyyy.zzzz.ApplicationKt.module ]
    }
    service {    }
    database {    }
    auth{    }
}

Comment: May the problem be in the request headers, which are more than 1024 bytes? Can you tweak the settings in the `application.conf` file to determine which causes 400 status?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman, after increasing the header length in application.conf, it is accepting the request now. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, just for reference, the issue was that the app service was appending large header to the request and the Ktor server was responding with 400. Updating application.conf with max header/request length solved the issue.

```
deployment {
    maxInitialLineLength = 10240
    maxHeaderSize = 8192
    maxChunkSize = 42
}
```